# Fixing ground "open circuit" on printed circuit board

Tags: short-circuit

I was installing a RV roof vent fan and accidentally shorted it (connected it in reverse polarity).

The short seems pretty clean and I was able to manually confirmed that nothing else was broken by manually bridging the short with a piece of wire held in place.

[image]

I was wondering what the **easiest** way to fix this would be (I'm more of a software than an hardware guy)... I was thinking maybe I could just put a bead of solder where its broken?

Comment: Component leg plus solder.

Comment: I realize I'm probably using incorrect vernacular.  If so, please correct me!

Comment: Solder in a little short piece of wire.

Comment: It would be a short if two connections were bridged where they shouldn't be.  You have a open spot in the trace.  It appears that some component has been blown completely off the board.  There appear to be the remains of some surface mounted part at each end of the break.  I would NOT placeca piece of wire there unless you can confirm that there should really only be a length of copper trace in that spot.  You would probably do better to replace the board.

Comment: @JRE When I first pulled the board, it wasn't a clean break like this but instead looked burnt and wrinkled... The green mask flaked off when I touched it to what it looks like in the photo.

Comment: also, every other service mounted component is enclosed in a white box with a identifier... I'm fairly certain there wasn't anything there... but I'm very novice around this type of stuff

Comment: @JRE, there would probably be silkscreen if there were a component, this looks like a trace break (probably from over-current) to me

Comment: Looks like the diode D6 is there to try to protect against reverse polarity connections, but instead of blowing a fuse further up-stream (you are connecting this device to a reasonably-sized fused circuit aren't you?) that little section of track on the PCB acted as the fuse.

Comment: @brhans I connected directly to a 12v to test :0 (like I said... novice)  It will have a 3 amp fuse when I install it for real

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solder won't bridge that gasp by itself - you'll need to solder a short bit of wire over the gap.

You will need to scrape some of the green solder mask off the undamaged portion of the track so you can solder to it.

Answer (score 3):

The terminology here needs a bit of clarification.

A short circuit is defined as two points in the circuit being connected together with theoretically zero resistance and therefore zero voltage drop between them. You can "short" two points in a circuit by connecting them with a conductor such as a wire.

An open circuit is defined as two points in the circuit being disconnected from each other entirely (theoretically, with infinite resistance between them, so that no current flows from one point to the other). You can "open" two points in a circuit by cutting the wire between them or physically disconnecting them in some other way.

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you actually have two points that should be connected but are not. That is an open circuit. In order to solve this problem, you need to short the circuit (connecting the two points back together). You can do this by taking a small wire or other conductor and connecting each end to the two solder points shown in the photo, then using a soldering iron to melt the solder and affix the wire in place.